# "Unable to infer schema for JSON." error in PySpark?

Tags: json, file, apache-spark, pyspark, schema

I have a `json` file with about 1,200,000 records.
I want to read this file with `pyspark` as :

```py
spark.read.option("multiline","true").json('file.json')
```

But it causes this error:

> AnalysisException: Unable to infer schema for JSON. It must be specified manually.

When I create a `json` file with a smaller record count in the main file, this code can read the file.

I can read this `json` file with `pandas`, when I set the `encoding` to `utf-8-sig`:

```py
pd.read_json("file.json", encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Since adding the encoding helps, maybe the following is what you need:

```py
spark.read.json("file.json", multiLine=True, encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: I test this. But it dos not solved my problem

Comment: You should post your data example, because this option normally works. There's something with your data/ schema.

Comment: Unfortunately I can share my data. thanks a lot

Answer (score -2):

Try this out:

```
spark.read.option("multiline","true").option("inferSchema", "true").json('file.json')
```

Comment: I test this. But it dos not solved my problem